# C - print member linked list passed by ref

Tags: c, list

This code won't print the value of the 'value member'.
There are a few comment on the code. I suspect error is on dereferencing.
It should print zero but instead print random integer

```
//Doubly Linked List
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Struct NODE
typedef struct node
{
  char index;
  unsigned int value;
  struct node *next;
  struct node *prev;

 } NODE;

 //Advance by 1 slot and print its value
 void printIndex(NODE **node){

    //deference one time and get next address
    (*node) = (*node)->next;

    //deference again and get value integer
    printf("->%d\n",(*node)->value);//<- I would expect zero but it doesn't
 }

 int main()
 {
   //Pointer to struct 
   NODE **ptr;

   //Initialize struct NODE 
   NODE* a = &(NODE) {.index = 0, .next = NULL, .prev = NULL, .value = 0 };
   NODE* b = &(NODE) {.index = 1, .next = NULL, .prev = NULL, .value = 0 };

   //Reserve space for nodes    
   a = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
   b = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

   //Link nodes    
   a->next = b;
   b->prev = a;

   //Start from (NODE) 'a' and pass its pointer to printIndex( NODE **ptr)
   ptr= &a;
   printIndex(ptr); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do a malloc. a and b are already pointing to something on the stack. The malloc call overrides what a and b were originally pointing to. Therefore, you get random values for `value`